# Alpine unsatisfiable constraints: missing packages

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am trying to create a docker image based on `alpine:3.7`, but I get errors while installing some packages with `apk add`.

Example:

```
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  apache2-suexec (missing):
    required by: world[apache2-suexec-custom]
  host (missing):
    required by: world[host]
  lpr (missing):
    required by: world[lpr]
  time (missing):
    required by: world[time]
```

The cause is that these packages do not exist in alpine repositories yet. How can I solve these issues? Is there any repository from which I can download them?

I'm using this line

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache add --update tcl apache2 apache2-suexec ca-certificates \ 
    apk-tools curl build-base supervisor lpr time dcron host rsync libxml2-utils libxslt
```

Comment: look at https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?file=&path=&name=apache2&branch=v3.7&repo=main&arch=x86_64

Comment: Try with `apk add [package] --no-cache` flag.

Comment: Of course, I did that.

Comment: Can you show your `Dockerfile`?

Comment: I've added the code that I'm using to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have an issue with the following packages: `apache2-suexec`, `host`, `lpr` and `time`.

Alpine has some other package structure than main Linux OSs:

- `apache2-suexec` is a part of `apache2` package;
- `host` is a part of `bind-tools` package;
- `lpr` is a part of `cups-client` package;
- `time` is already in alpine image. It uses `busybox`'s `time` utility.

So, the final `Dockerfile` is:

```
FROM alpine:3.7

RUN apk update \
    && apk upgrade \
    && apk --no-cache add --update tcl apache2 ca-certificates \ 
    apk-tools curl build-base supervisor cups-client dcron bind-tools rsync libxml2-utils libxslt
```

Comment: This is exactly the mapping that I needed. Thanks!